# Javascript Rearrange array by same object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

What I have:

```
myArray = [ {type: "My Application"}, {type: "My Component"}, {color: ["red"] } ]
```

What I need:

```
withUniqueKeys = [ {type: ["My Application", "My Component"] }, {color: ["red"]} ]
```

How would I loop through myArray to get an array like withUniquKeys?  I've been toying with this WAAAYYYY too long. A lodash solution would be okay too.

Comment: do you have only `type` and `color` or different and/or more properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
let myArray = [ {type: "My Application"}, {type: "My Component"}, {color: "red" } ]

let op = myArray.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  let [key,value] = Object.entries(inp)[0]
  op[key] = op[key] || []
  op[key].push(value)
  return op
},{})

// in case you want property with one value to be object only

let final = Object.entries(op)
           .map(([key,value]) => ( {[key]: value.length === 1 ? value[0] : value}))

console.log(final)
```

IMO it's better to keep you structure of data consistent something like this,so it becomes easy to use for later purposes else you need to check whether the value is just a string or array and than apply methods

```js
let myArray = [ {type: "My Application"}, {type: "My Component"}, {color: "red" } ]

let op = myArray.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  let [key,value] = Object.entries(inp)[0]
  op[key] = op[key] || []
  op[key].push(value)
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Apparently OP doesn't want arrays if there is only one value (e.g. `color`).

Comment: @Jeto updated for that case too, but IMO it's better to have a consistent strcture

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Reduce initial array to group entries by keys
2. Map object entries to array of corresponding objects

```js
let myArray = [ {type: "My Application"}, {type: "My Component"}, {color: ["red"] } ]

myArray = myArray.reduce((acc, el) => {
  let prop = Object.keys(el)[0];
  if (!acc[prop]) acc[prop] = [el[prop]];
  else acc[prop].push(el[prop])
  return acc;
},{})

myArray = Object.keys(myArray).map(d => ({[d]:myArray[d].length ===1?myArray[d][0]:myArray[d]}));

console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) like this:

```js
const arr = [{type: "My Application"}, {type: "My Component"}, {color: "red" }];

const result = Object.entries(arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
  Object.entries(x).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    acc[k] = [...(acc[k] || []), v];
  });
  return acc;
}, {})).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v.length > 1 ? v : v[0] }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do the grouping by the `keys`. Then, on a second step, you can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the generated [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the desired structure:

```js
let myArray = [
  {type: "My Application", category: "game"},
  {type: "My Component", category: "other"},
  {color: "red" }
];

let res = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) =>
{
    Object.keys(curr).forEach(k =>
    {
        acc[k] = (acc[k] || []).concat(curr[k]);
    });
    return acc;
}, {});

res = Object.entries(res).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v.length > 1 ? v : v[0]}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note, this approach will also work if your input objects have more then one pair of `key/value`.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers look fine, here's a short alternative, also using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const myArray = [{type: "My Application"}, {type: "My Component"}, {color: "red"}];

const withUniqueKeys = Object.entries(
  myArray.reduce((result, item) => {
    const [key, val] = Object.entries(item)[0];
    result[key] = result[key] ? [...[result[key]], val] : val;
    return result;
  }, {})
).map(([key, val]) => ({[key]: val}));

console.log(withUniqueKeys);
```